Network monitoring tool
I need a network monitoring solution that can automatically adjust threshold values of all the devices in a network. Please recommend what you use in your orgs.

Yeah this is asking for something specific, a network monitoring tool that can automatically adjust threshold values of all the devices in a network.

In what world is that specific? Threshold values of what? What kind of devices? What do those devices run? How do they do authentication? This is as vague a question as they come - people say "don't just dump your homework here", and this is the office version of that.
